# SQL - need help writing/modifying query

Tags: mysql, sql, tags, group-concat

I've battling with this for a few days now and as SQL is not something I use too often I can't get my query to work the way I want it to.

I have a simple test database for tagging records using "toxi" solution (three tables, one acts as a link "ProgramCourses")

My tables

```
Program:

 - ProgramID : int
 - ProgramName : varchar

Course:

 - CourseID : int
 - CourseName : varchar

ProgamCourses:

 - ProgramID : int
 - CourseID : int
```

What I'm trying to do is to collect all tags as string and then add them as a new column to Program table.

My query

```
SELECT  * , GROUP_CONCAT(c.CourseName) AS tags_list
FROM `Program` p
LEFT JOIN ProgramCourses AS pc ON p.ProgramID = pc.ProgramID
LEFT JOIN Course AS c ON pc.CourseID = c.CourseID
GROUP BY p.ProgramID
ORDER BY p.ProgramID
```

this kinda does what I need but it duplicates some columns and result I get is:

```
ProgramID   ProgramName     ProgramID   CourseID    CourseID    CourseName  tags_list
```

instead of

```
ProgramID   ProgramName     CourseName
```

Any help would be very appreciated.
If someone is kind enough to write a query for me could you please write it with full names of tables and columns as this would make it easier for me to understand and adopt for other purposes.
Thank you.

T.

Comment: Don't do it.  If you want the tags as a string, then calculate it when you are querying.

Comment: Don't use evil `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT c.CourseName` Returns a count of the number of rows with different CourseName.

```
SELECT  * , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.CourseName) AS tags_list
FROM `Program` p
LEFT JOIN ProgramCourses AS pc ON p.ProgramID = pc.ProgramID
LEFT JOIN Course AS c ON pc.CourseID = c.CourseID
GROUP BY p.ProgramID
ORDER BY p.ProgramID
```

For More Info visit it [Official](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  * , GROUP_CONCAT(c.CourseName) AS tags_list
FROM `Program` p
LEFT JOIN ProgramCourses AS pc using(ProgramID)
LEFT JOIN Course AS c using(CourseID)
GROUP BY p.ProgramID
ORDER BY p.ProgramID
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This kinda does what I want when tested in phpMyAdmin but when called out from PHP file I get error "Fatal error: Failed parsing SQL query on select: SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT(c.CourseName) AS tags_list FROM `Program` p LEFT JOIN ProgramCourses AS pc USING (ProgramID) LEFT JOIN Course AS c USING (CourseID) GROUP BY p.ProgramID ORDER BY p.ProgramID . The Error was Parse error: Unexpected clause on line 3 LEFT JOIN ProgramCourses AS pc USING (ProgramID) ^ found: "USING" in C:\UwAmp\www\xataface-2.1.1\lib\SQL\Parser.php on line 1773". Any ideas? Thanks.